# Get a constant name as a string

Tags: php, curl

I'm writing a wrapper class for cURL which, when you set an option, saves the option name to an array so that I can manage which options are set.

The problem is that with cURL option names being constants, they are actually integers so I can't really tell which options have been set.

Excerpt from the class:

```
class Curl {

    protected $_options;

    public function setOption($name, $value) {
        $result = curl_setopt($this->_handle, $name, $value);
        if ($result) {
            $this->_options[$name] = $value;
        }
        return $result;
    }

}
```

Let's say I set the following options:

```
array(
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30
)
```

The `Curl::_options` will then look like:

```
array(
    (int) 78 => (int) 10,
    (int) 42 => (int) 0,
    (int) 47 => (int) 1,
    (int) 19913 => (int) 1,
    (int) 13 => (int) 30
)
```

How can I get the actual names of the cURL constants?  Is this possible using the [Reflection class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.construct.php)?

Comment: Reflection would retrieve this, as might using the PHP tokeniser

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get the name of the constant by its value - for example, what to do if many constants share the same value? You can, of course, go the long way: first call [get_defined_constants](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php), then flip the resulting array. The real question is, why do you need that?

Comment: @MarkBaker An example please of either? @raina77ow I don't want to get the name of the constant by its value, I want to get the constant name `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` as a literal string `'CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT'`.

Comment: @BadHorsie Can you explain the difference? You have some value - 78, that is the value of `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` constant, and you want to convert it into a string literal 'CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT', right? But what if 78 is also a value of the `CURL_SOMETHING_SOMETHING` constant?

Comment: @raina77ow That's right.  One is human readable, the other is just an integer.

Comment: Ok, to which string should value `10009` be converted: `'CURLOPT_READDATA'` or `'CURLOPT_INFILE'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, technically there's a way to prepare an array with `curl` constant names as strings and their values as, well, values:

```
$curl_constants = get_defined_constants(true)['curl'];
```

As you seem to deal only with `CURLOPT` constants, you can refine it:

```
$curlopt_constants = [];
foreach ($curl_constants as $constant_name => $constant_value) {
  if (strpos($constant_name, 'CURLOPT') === 0) {
    $curlopt_constants[$constant_name] = $constant_value;
  }
}
```

The problem is, several constants in these array still have the same value (`CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD`, `CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD` and `CURLOPT_KEYPASSWD` => `10026`; `CURLOPT_READDATA` and `CURLOPT_INFILE` => `10009`). If you're OK with this ambiguity, you can flip this array, turning it into a hash.

```
$curlopt_constants_hash = array_flip($curlopt_constants);
```

Then you can get the string literal just by looking in this hash:

```
$curlopt_constant_name = 
    isset($curlopt_constants_hash[$constant_value])
        ? $curlopt_constants_hash[$constant_value]
        : null
;
```

That (checking hash) is faster than using `array_search` on the array.

Comment: So there is no real way to do this due to different constants having the same value?  Do you know why they have the same value? What do the numbers correspond to?  I thought they would be unique.